# Classic ASP Intellisense ADODB Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp-classic, intellisense, adodb

I am using Visual Studio to edit my classic asp web site and intellisense and colour coding works for most part, i.e. if I type "Response." then it pops up with a list of options.

However when I use a declared object type such as;
Set DB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

I no longer get intellisense options when I type "DB."

I used to get intellisense when using MicroSoft Interdev (blast from the past) to edit ASP files and it would be handy to get it back.

My question is therefore, does anyone know of a way with VS2010 (or later) in which I can re-enable intellisense for Server Created objects ?

Many thanks

Matt

Comment: Is the issue with all COM objects or just ADODB?  For example, try `set msg = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")`, and see if you get intellisense when you type "msg.".  I have a dual boot machine.  On Windows 7 I get no intellisense for ADODB objects but when I run it in Win 8 I do. I suspect the answer lies in which dll is registered.  I asked a question about this about three years ago, It got no replies and it was eventually deleted.  I also found this thread on msdn which gave no satisfactory answer.

Comment: This thread on MSDN may be of interest, although there's no satisfactory answer. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73615acc-1cc0-4dfc-bcc1-f86a416de8a7/the-intellisense-does-not-work-for-any-adodb-objects-with-vs2008vs2010-in-windows-7?forum=vbide

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VS2015 and it works for me, but the file must have an ASP extension.  And it only works in direct scope of the Created object.

For example:

```
  set command = CreateCommandWithParameters(Me.conn, parameterizedQuery, values)
   Command.... 'no intellisense here because Server.CreateObject was called in a Function elsewhere
```

But I get intellisense below just fine.

```
Private Function CreateCommand(connection, query, commandType)
    if (commandType <> adCmdText AND commandType <> adCmdTable AND commandType <> adCmdStoredProc AND commandType <> adCmdFile AND commandType <> adCmdTableDirect) then Err.Raise 16001, "Invalid Command Type", "Must be, adCmdText, adCmdTable, adCmdStoredProc, adCmdFile, adCmdTableDirect"
    Set CreateCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set CreateCommand.ActiveConnection = connection
    CreateCommand.ActiveConnection = connection     
    CreateCommand.NamedParameters = true   
    CreateCommand.CommandText = query
    CreateCommand.CommandType = commandType
    CreateCommand.CommandTimeout = 120 '2 minutes....        
    CreateCommand.Prepared = true     
End Function
```

It could also be because I have the TypeLib imported in the Global.asa

```
<!--METADATA TYPE="TypeLib" file="C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll" -->
```

As a final note, while it does work on Server.CreateObject in some cases..... It does not work on user defined subs, classes, and functions...

I've basically just gotten use to not having intellisense.  VBScript is not case sensitive so it hasn't bothered me to much.

Comment: Ok, figured out another thing.  Intellisense works on user defined functions, classes, and more as well, but only if they are defined in the page being edited.  The visual studio editor is not smart enough to provide Intellisense on server side includes.....

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I tried using the TypeLib within the global.asa (having checked the path to the dll), but i still cannot get the intellisense to work. And yes i have also noticed that VS does not have the brains to work out server side includes and pick up function / sub names from includes files.  I will do some more digging around the global.asa option as that seems the most likely route for success.

Comment: @RyanMann - I don't know if you're still using SO, if you are could you say which Windows version you're using.  My theory is that this bug is specific to ADODB objects and specific to Windows 7.  That can possibly be narrowed down to Win7 SP1

Comment: Windows 10, I mean, going back to XP and a 32 bit OS isn't really an option.  I don't really do Classic ASP anymore though.